# Xcode 8 weird log messages - how to turn them off

Tags: ios, xcode, logging, xcode8

Since I started using Xcode 8 for iOS 10 development, my console gets flooded with all kinds of logs that I did not activate. In Xcode 7.3.x they did not appear:

```
[] nw_endpoint_handler_cancel [22.2 23.23.94.109:443 initial path (null)]
[] nw_endpoint_handler_cancel [22.3 23.23.98.165:443 initial path (null)]
[] nw_endpoint_handler_cancel [22.4 23.23.161.173:443 initial path (null)]
[] nw_endpoint_handler_cancel [22.5 50.17.182.35:443 initial path (null)]
[] nw_endpoint_handler_cancel [22.6 50.17.185.176:443 initial path (null)]
[] nw_endpoint_handler_cancel [22.7 50.17.217.30:443 initial path (null)]
[] nw_endpoint_handler_cancel [22.8 23.23.77.27:443 initial path (null)]
[] nw_resolver_cancel_on_queue 0x610000111700
[] -[NWConcrete_tcp_connection dealloc] 22
```

How can I turn them off? Or does someone know which library could cause them?